# Do NSUserActivity-based Siri shortcuts support custom UI?

Tags: ios, siri, sirikit, sirishortcuts, nsuseractivity

Do NSUserActivity-based shortcuts support custom UI?

I've created a custom Siri Shortcuts with the help of a custom Intent. I was able to create both a UI-less version (just `Intent`) and a version with the custom UI (`IntentsUI`) which is shown during inline interaction with Siri. Is it possible to have a custom UI with the `NSUserActivity`-based shortcuts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Apple made it very clear in their [WWDC presentation](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/211/) that Siri Shortcuts are divided into two, one using Intents and one using NSUserActivity.

The IntentsUI extension is specifically for those who use the Intents framework.

Comment: Thanks for clarification!